# Clojure order hash map by value using key name as tiebreaker

Tags: clojure

I'd like to be able to sort a hash-map by the value of it's keys, using the key name itself in the event of a tie

I have an an ordering function taken from the Clojure wiki https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-map-by#example-542692d5c026201cdc327094

```
(defn order-map [target]
  (into (sorted-map-by (fn [key1 key2]
                         (compare [(target key2) key2]
                                  [(target key1) key1]))) target))
```

Currently I'm able to do

```
(-> "notarealroom" frequencies order-map)
```

which outputs

```
{\o 3, \r 2, \a 2, \t 1, \n 1, \m 1, \l 1, \e 1}
```

but I'd like to be able to sort those keys with the same value, e.g. `\r` and `\a` alphabetically to give something like the following...

```
{\o 3, \a 2, \r 2, \e 1, \l 1, \m 1, \n 1, \t 1}
```

I'm unsure how to modify the compare function to deal with this tie-break scenario

Comment: Are you doing Advent of Code? I also solved this problem, but didn't need a sort map. It's sufficient to just sort the result of frequencies. If you want my full solution, peek at https://github.com/borkdude/aoc2016.

Comment: You guessed correct, I'm just trying to improve my pretty basic Clojure. Your solution is super neat! many thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. The following should do the right thing:

```
(defn order-map [target]
  (into (sorted-map-by (fn [key1 key2]
                         (compare [(target key2) key1]
                                  [(target key1) key2]))) target))
```